# Yelp business ID code with Yelp API

Tags: api, yelp

I have a .csv file of yelp reviews that I must use. It gives an alphanumeric id for each user and business(possibly review). I haven't been able to find any way of using these codes to locate the associated business' yelp page. The codes look like this...

"TR0-w6VoZDAdvFQiq7P2Ug" for Capriotti's Sandwich Shop

"pLZ9oZM8c6MNbRlg06lBPg" for Impact Auto Glass & Tint

etc...

I don't have any other info on these businesses that I could potentially use. I really want to be able to use Yelp's API to find image URLs (which I have been able to use), but haven't had any luck translating the info in my .csv file to something the API can use.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I wrote up this example, if you have an express server running you can paste in and try it out -

```
// using express
// client - refers to yelp-fusion.client - checkout yelp-fusion NPM

app.get('/reviews', (req, res) => {
  let id = 'TR0-w6VoZDAdvFQiq7P2Ug';
  // id example from your Comment

  client.reviews(id).then(response => {
    // find review from ID given in CSV File:

    let url = new URL(response.jsonBody.reviews[0].url);

    // parse URL using url-parse package, return just pathname

    let bizName = url.pathname.substring(5,url.pathname.length);

    // every yelp pathname begins with /biz/ - use substring to return only biz name

    // now use that bizName to look up business - which will have image url within response:

    client.business(bizName)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.jsonBody);
      let featuredImgUrl = response.jsonBody.image_url;
      let photos = response.jsonBody.photos;
      res.json(photos)
    });
  }).catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
    res.json('Error');
  });
})
```